# How to programmatically set JVM properties in Play 2.5?

Tags: playframework, jvm

From the documentation, I can simply set the properties as below:

> `$ /path/to/bin/<project-name> -J-Xms128M -J-Xmx512m -J-server`

Is it possible to set these properties in the play configuration?

Comment: No. Those are JVM properties, and when Play loads its config the JVM is already created.

Comment: can you elaborate more about this?

Comment: Sure. Those properties are passed to the jvm when it starts (for example: `java -Xmx32m  -jar someapp.jar` will set the max memory to 32mb) and cannot be changed later. So the jvm is started, play is loaded and only after that Play configuration will be read. Unless you write some script that parses the contents of your conf files and pass those to the startup script, just setting it in the Play configuration wont work...